# Codigo php funciona en servidor local pero no funciona en servidor externo

Tags: php, servidor, hosting

todo mi codigo php funciona muy bien en mi servidor local de mi PC pero cuando lo subi a servidor externo dejo de funcionar y me sale muchos errores, ya cambie a ambas a la misma versión 8.1 y sigue igual con los errores

```
    <?php 
    
    include '../conexion.php';
    
    ?>
    
    <?php
    
    session_start();
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: ../login.php");
    exit;
    }
    
    $iduser = $_SESSION["id"];
    
    $sql = "SELECT id, usuario, email, apellidos_nombres, profesion, user_descripcion, imageperfil FROM usuarios WHERE id ='$iduser'";
    
    $resultado = $link->query($sql);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) as total  FROM `proyectos` where id_usuario= ".$row['id'] ;
$result = $link->query($sql);
$fila = $result->fetch_assoc();
    
    ?>
```

Errores en el servidor externo

[image: Errores que me da el servidor]

Espero me puedan ayudar estoy desesperado

Comment: Por regla la instrucción `session_start()` debe estar al inicio del documento . Es probable que la configuración del php.ini sea distinta a la de producción por ello en local no figura el error.

Comment: Y como soluciono eso  :(

Comment: Mueve el `session_start()` al inicio de todo el script antes de escribir por pantalla cualquier `div` o contenido

Comment: El error con los headers y session_start se da porque tu error está imprimiendo en la salida _antes_ de ejecutar el session_start. El problema de fondo es que tus consultas están fallando y no es claro el por qué. No sabemos cómo moviste la BD en tu entorno local a la BD en el servidor externo y si validaste que el dato que buscas exista. `row[id]` puede estar vacío y la consulta tendría una sintaxis inválida

Answer (score 1):

session_start();
deberia de ir al principio , para evitar aunque no se si sea tu caso por si usas librerias externas que usen variables de session puedes utilizar este fragmento de codigo para verificar si se ejecuto session_start() antes o no.

```
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
   session_start();
}
```

include '../conexion.php';

Answer (score 0):

El session debes definir en tus template principal o php principal de tu proyecto que inicializa todo no en el la clase de conexion el error anuncia que estas llamando mas de una vez a `session_start();`
declara una sola vez session_start(); en el php principal que llama a clase conexion.